# Converting HyperV 2008R2 image to 2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have a HyperV 2008R2 VHD image created with a 2008R2 based template configuration being - 2G RAM, 40GB disk, 2 CPUs and 2 bridge port network interfaces.

Would like to know if it is possible to covert my existing 2008R2 VHD image to 2012R2 VHDX version making the instance run over HyperV 2012R2 ? If yes what procedure to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talk only about the disc, then start stripping out the useless elements - like the server versions. It runs down to "can I convert a VHD to a VHDX". And yes, that is fully supported. Command line, menu in Hyper-V manage (edit disc).

If you talk about the VM, it is a 2 step process. Export in 2008, import in 2012R2. THEN edit the disc and link the new VHDX into the VM.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done via Hyper-V Manager: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/aviraj/2012/05/05/windows-server-2012-convert-vhd-to-vhdx-using-hyper-v-manager/

Alternatively, you can use third party converters such as StarWind V2V converter: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter It also has a bunch of extra conversion options (for example VMware to Hyper-V and vise versa).